# Regex for string between quotes and replace it

Tags: java, regex

Can you guys help me??

I have a string here :

```
a$20=A.createVar("/LIST/S_UNB/C_S001/D_0001/*var", a$1, this);
```

Now I want to replace the string in "" with the value that appears after last '/'.

here I want result to be

```
a$20=A.createVar("*var", a$1, this);
```

I am trying to use as minimal objects as possible and my regex looks like this

```
\"([^\"]*)\"
```

Is this correct?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: *"Is this correct?"* Does it work? If not then it's probably not correct.

Comment: I suspect it's `java` (according to the user's previous question).

Comment: `"/.*\/([^\/]+)"/"\1"/`

Comment: sorry ... its JAVA ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the quotes aren't part of the expression, use

```
[^/]+$
```

$ signifies the end of the string, which will make it return only the value after the last '/'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
String s = "a$20=A.createVar(\"/LIST/S_UNB/C_S001/D_0001/*var\", a$1, this);";
// extract text between ""
String sub = s.replaceAll("^[^\"]*\"([^\"]*)\".*$", "$1");
// find last index of /
int i = sub.lastIndexOf('/');
// replace content between "" by token after last /
String repl = s.replaceFirst("\"[^\"]*\"", '"' + sub.substring(i+1) + '"');
//=> a$20=A.createVar("*var", a$1, this);
```